# How to get the address field of a contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app, I want to get the address field of a selected contact. I managed to get the contact name but I don't know how to get the address. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(TAG, "name contact: "+ name);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
Cursor address_cursror = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (address_cursror.moveToNext())
                {

                    String name = address_cursror.getString(address_cursror.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String street = address_cursror.getString(address_cursror.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                    String state = address_cursror.getString(address_cursror.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                    String zip = address_cursror.getString(address_cursror.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                    String city = address_cursror.getString(address_cursror.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
            }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY`
`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET`
[ContactsContract Structured Postal docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.html)
Please check the dev docs before come here to ask question.